# Firebase not configured when it clearly is

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, sigabrt

I don't know why this isn't working my Firebase is configured.
Here is a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qsIV.png) of my AppDelegate.swift file. Here is my console log:

```
2017-05-29 17:52:53.141 Study M8[31592] <Error> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add [FIRApp configure] to your application initialization. Read more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize_firebase_in_your_app.
2017-05-29 17:52:53.184 Study M8[31592:1051241] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The default FIRApp instance must be configured before the default FIRAuthinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` is called in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a445b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109eaa141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4ae625 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Study M8                            0x0000000108550a84 +[FIRAuth auth] + 88
    4   Study M8                            0x00000001084e7a77 _TFC8Study_M810MessagesVCcfT5coderCSo7NSCoder_GSqS0__ + 279
    5   Study M8                            0x00000001084e7bcd _TToFC8Study_M810MessagesVCcfT5coderCSo7NSCoder_GSqS0__ + 45
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010ac70f54 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 246
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010ae614af UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 693
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010ae6164d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1107
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ae611ef -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010aa07267 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 1421
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010aa5cee5 -[UITabBarController initWithCoder:] + 65
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010ae614af UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 693
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010ae611ef -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010ac70c20 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 178
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010ae614af UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 693
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010ae6164d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1107
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010ae611ef -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010ac6fe1d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1262
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010b02882f -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010a8688d1 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 108
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010a868db3 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010a867456 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1407
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010a864793 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 182
    24  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d3205f6 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    25  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d32046d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 186
    26  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d3207f6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3ebc01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3d10cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3d05ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3d0016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010a86302f -[UIApplication _run] + 468
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010a8690d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    33  Study M8                            0x00000001084e8997 main + 55
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ca5665d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I have tried all afternoon to get this working. Please help.

Comment: 1. Close X-code 2.Clean `DrivedData` 3. Clean project and re-run.

Comment: Didn't work, I got the same error.

Comment: show me Podfile and minimum supported iOS version

Comment: Podfile Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNo1U.png
Deployment Info Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOBXf.png

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking in your stack trace, I get the impression you might be accessing the `Firebase.Auth` class too soon — maybe in the `initWithCoder` of your VC? Or as a VC property initial value?  — which could be *before* your `AppDelegate` runs (and initializes Firebase).

As such, try moving your `Auth.auth()` call to the `viewDidLoad` method instead to see if it makes a difference at all.

Comment: I removed Auth.auth().currentUser from a variable I had created. Thanks fro the help.

Comment: @JackStaples Glad to help ;)

Comment: Also I would suggest checking your AppDelegate initial properties -- don't setup any VCs in there that use Auth