# Can't implement Firebase across multiple Swift modules

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

This is for Firebase 6.26.0 and 6.27.0 (I've tried both for reasons that will become clear)

I have a Swift application I'm trying to decompose into modules from its current monolith, but so far I have not been able to expose Firebase classes across the modules (i.e frameworks) by installing Firebase pods in each individual module. It will only work when there is only one existing library, and when that library is installed in the application target, where it is instantiated in AppDelegate.

Does anyone know if it's possible to implement Firebase across multiple modules in a single workspace?

**Expected results**

That Firebase classes will be exposed to all modules in a multi-module Swift application, with one or more copies of the Firebase library present, allowing all modules to call Firebase methods and implement Firebase classes within a single, global instance of FirebaseApp.

**Actual results**

Either Firebase refuses to instantiate because of the presence of more than one Firebase library in the workspace, or, when only one library is present, Firebase classes cannot be exposed to other modules in the workspace.

**What I've done**

1. Installed individual Firebase pods in every module requiring them. On launch I got this error:
   .
   `The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the defaultFirebaseApp instance can be initialized`
   .
   According to an answer from a Firebase team member on [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61352175/2846510), this is caused by the presence of more than one Firebase library in the workspace.
2. Installed only one pod to create a "FirebaseProxy" module that both the application target and all other modules could share. By using typealiases and extensions I was able to let classes implement Firebase classes without having to be exposed to the actual Firebase library, for example:

```
    import Firebase

    public typealias FirebaseUserProxy = Firebase.User
    public extension FirebaseUserProxy {}
```

So this way an implementing class could use the `Firebase.User` type by using `FirebaseUserProxy` instead, and without having to be directly exposed to the Firebase library.
.
However, there were some proxied classes that still seemed to require being exposed to the full library. (My brain is a bit addled from dealing with all this so I've forgotten exactly which ones, I believe it was FirebaseApp.) But even using `@_exposed import Firebase` in the proxy definition didn't do the trick, and I only got the message `Missing required module 'Firebase'`.

3. Same solution as in #2, but using `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` in my Podfile. No luck. And yes, I did try using `$(SRCROOT)/Stat` in my frameworks search paths build settings.
4. Finally I tried integrating the library directly into my project without using Cocoapods. Here I was using 6.26.0 since the Firebase download link with a `6.27.0` in the URL resulted in a `Not Found` message, so I manually changed it to `6.26.0` and that downloaded fine
   .
   I installed the library in the application and in another module, hoping that somehow this method would obscure each library from the other, but ended up with the same error message as in #1... `The default FirebaseApp...`
   .
   I also tried using the proxy method from #2, but that resulted in the same error.
   .
   I had to set `:linkage => :static` in my Podfile so the installed pods would play nicely with the integrated library. Turning it off resulted in an error.

**Alternatives**

1. If I can't get this to work, I may have to refactor my code so that the Firebase-dependent code exists in the application itself instead of a standalone framework module. This would not impact functionality, but it would break the architecture and make the code a good deal more convoluted and brittle.
2. There is a [solution on the Firebase git repo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/936#issuecomment-610322573) (that I haven't tried), that suggests reverting back to v.6.15.0. I am reluctant to do this though since the most recent release is at 6.27.0 and I don't want to be unable to upgrade and risk using an older version that later releases will undoubtedly break eventually.

**Finally**

It's disappointing that such a widely used and vital tool can only be used in monolith applications, basically limiting developers to a single, often suboptimal, type of architecture.  Have I missed something? Maybe. It wouldn't be the first time. But if anyone can light the way out of my dilemma I would be happy to buy you a beer, and given the current social distancing regulations, consume it on your behalf.

Comment: The 6.27.0 zip download problem has been fixed - but won't help with this problem. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2022 planned for the next major Firebase iOS SDK release should help but is still at least a few months away.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PaulBeusterien. Good to know this fix is planned. In the meantime I've figured out a fairly robust workaround that I can live with -- abstracting and injecting Firebase methods into out of scope classes. Maybe a bit messy, but good enough for government work as they say.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that @oaker?

Comment: @oaker Did you find any solution for this problem? I'm looking for the same result (linking Firebase products to different frameworks) but I started out using SPM which was a total failure. But manually integrating the frameworks didn't work as well. Firebase did some work on .xcframeworks so SPM might work now but I'm reluctant to try since it took so long to get to a submittable state :D currently link all Firebase fmwks to a Tracking target but semantically there is more happening than just tracking so I want to finally split this up into multiple frameworks