# How to use Using Firebase SDKs from static frameworks in Cocoa pods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to update Firebase version SDK in the project, but cause Firebase SDKs was used in pos as dynamic frameworks, as cause it is by different targets inside the app, it cause app to crash. After reading :
[Morgan Chen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60753233/the-default-firebaseapp-instance-must-be-configured-before-the-defaultfirebaseap)

[Firebase page](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/docs/firebase_in_libraries.md)

How to organise pod file to make it work properly?

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

use_frameworks!(:linkage => :static)

platform :ios, '10.0'

workspace 'MainProject'

project 'someSDK/someSDK.xcodeproj'
project 'MainProject/MainProject.xcodeproj'

def common_pods

```
pod 'AFNetworking'

use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

end

target :someSDKPresentation do
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

```
pod 'AFNetworking'

project 'someSDK/someSDK.xcodeproj'
```

end

target :someSDKCommon do

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
pod 'AFNetworking'

use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

project 'someSDK/someSDK.xcodeproj'
```

end

target :MainProject do
common_pods
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'TwitterKit'

```
project 'MainProject/MainProject.xcodeproj'
```

end

target :MainProjectDev do
common_pods
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'TwitterKit'

```
project 'MainProject/MainProject.xcodeproj'
```

end

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did u find something?

Comment: Yes I communicated with Firebase support and they helped me with this.

Comment: @LMaker I moved whole projects that I use into my project, thats it. And it was the only proper solution in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only one proper solution in my case was to add whole Firebase libraries that I need.
I lookes like this:
[image: Static libraries]