Firebase Upgrade to 10.24.0. Unit Test are failing with 'FirebaseApp' instance must be configured even though App has FirebaseApp.configure call
I have tried many solutions given on Stackoverflow as well as on github. However, none of them are working. So I am trying to provide more details on the issue I am facing.
Using XCode: 15.3
Upgrade firebase SDKs from 7.8.0 to 10.24.0,
However after this upgrade, my app is crashing for Test Cases and the error says,

"The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the
default Remote Config instance can be initialized. One way to ensure
this is to call FirebaseApp.configure() in the App Delegate's
application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) or the @main
struct's initializer in SwiftUI."

Although the Firebase initialisation is already there in the AppDelegate,
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
}

I have tried some solutions given in this link:
The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the defaultFirebaseApp instance can be initialized
Especially this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61352175/3825016
Tried defining Firebase as a static library in the Podfile,
pod 'Firebase/Core', '10.24.0' do
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
end
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '10.24.0' do
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
end
pod 'FirebaseInAppMessaging', '10.24.0-beta' do
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
end
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '10.24.0' do
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
end
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '10.24.0' do
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
end

Still getting the same crash while running the test cases in my project.
I even found this discussion thread on Github: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11521
Issue seems similar, but no solution given.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Have you tried deleting your Derived Data or downgrading your XCode? XCode 15 might be having bugs.
